# Reactjs nested state and child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I use React/ImmutableJS in a large application with many nested data and state. Some "nested" data are passed to child components through props.

The child components deals with props like local variables (there is no mutation since props are immutable) : they returns a new copy to the parent component which update its own state.

A simple example :

```
const user = Immutable.Map({
    name: '...',
    accessRights: Immutable.Map({
        preferences: true,
        contact: false,
       ....
    })
});

class Admin extends Component {
    state = { user };

    render() {
        return <AccessRights
            rights={user.get('accessRights')}
            onRightsChange={newRights =>
                this.setState({ user: user.set('accessRights', newRights) })
            }
        />
    }
}

class AccessRights extends Component {
    render() {
        const { rights, onRightsChange } = this.props;

        return <div>
            {rights.entrySeq().map(([key, value]) =>
                <input
                    key={key}
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={value}
                    onChange={e => onRightsChange(rights.set(key, e.target.checked))}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. If you need additional clarification, or reassurance, look no further than to React's own docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: If an `AccessRights` component's state does not need to be computed from the others, then I would recommend simplifying the fact that you're re-rendering the `AccessRights` components *each time*, without possibly needing to. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check a React `<input>` component's value against the "`nextState`" (parameter value commonly used to reference the passed value in `shouldComponentUpdate`)

Comment: for larger application, its recommended to use flex architecture to easy state management. You will lost if you go with statefull components like above.